# View all Data of two related tables , even if something is not registered from table A to table B

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

i have two sql server table like this :

```
[Management].[Person](  
[PersonsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,   
[FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL, 
[LastName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,    
[Semat] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,    
[Vahed] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,    
[Floor] [int] NOT NULL,     
[ShowInList] [bit] NOT NULL,    
[LastState] [nchar](10) NOT NULL)
```

and

```
[Management].[PersonEnters](
    [PersonEnters] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Vaziat] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Time] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [PDate] [nchar](10) NOT NULL)
```

that PersonsID in second table is a foreign key.
i register every person's enter to system on PersonsEnter Table.
i want to show all person enter stastus in a certain date (PDate field) , if a person entered to system show it's information an if did not, show null insted,
i tried this query :

```
select  * from [Management].[Person] left outer join [Management].[PersonEnters]
on [Management].[Person].[PersonsID] = [Management].[PersonEnters].[PersonID]
 where [Management].[PersonEnters].PDate = '1392/11/14'
```

but it just shows registered person enter data at 1392/11/14 and shows nothing for others,
i wanna show this data plus null or a constant string like "NOT REGISTERED" for other persons that not registered their enter in PersonEnters Table on '1392/11/14'. Please Help Me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, the WHERE clause will be applied after the join. If some `Person` entries do not have matches in `PersonEnters`, they will have NULLs in `PDate` as a result of the join, but the WHERE clause will filter them out because the comparison `NULL = '1392/11/14'` will not yield `true`.

If I understand your question correctly, you essentially want an outer join to a *subset* of `PersonEnters` (the one where `PDate = '1392/11/14'`), not to the *entire* table. One way to express that could be like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Management.Person AS p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM Management.PersonEnters
  WHERE PDate = '1392/11/14'
) AS pe
ON p.Person.ID = pe.PersonID
;
```

As you can see, this query very explicitly tells the server that a particular subset should be derived from `PersonEnters` before the join takes place – because you want to indicate matches with that particular subset, not with the whole table.

However, the same intent could be rewritten in a more concise way (without a derived table):

```
SELECT *
FROM Management.Person AS p
LEFT JOIN Management.PersonEnters AS pe
  ON p.Person.ID = pe.PersonID AND pe.PDate = '1392/11/14'
;
```

The effect of the above query would be the same and you would get all `Person` entries, with matching results from `PersonEnters` only if they have `PDate = '1392/11/14'`.

Comment: if i wanna get monthly report what can i do? i meant for every day get a full list of person that registered in PersonEnters or not. something like daily time sheet per month

Comment: You are probably after something similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675947/mysql-n-to-n-double-join-with-null-cross-join-from-answer "mySql N to N double join with null - CROSS join from answer"). And the approach in the accepted answer would really be your solution then. The cross-joined tables would be `Person` and a table of dates, and the left-joined table would be `PersonEnters`. Feel free to post a new question if you have issues implementing that. (But do try to solve it yourself first – you'll have much more fun that way!)

Answer (score 0):

```
select  * 
  from [Management].[Person] 
  left outer join [Management].[PersonEnters]
    on [Management].[Person].[PersonsID] = [Management].[PersonEnters].[PersonID]
   and [Management].[PersonEnters].PDate = '1392/11/14'
```

Comment: I registered all enters on Management.PersonEnters table, if user a enters on Sunday and not enter on Monday,if i run this query on Monday user a will be omitted from query result, and if for example on Thursday all persons entered, i get wrong result

Comment: So not clear.  Fix the question.   Your comment is not consistent with "for other persons that not registered".

Comment: If a person has an entry in `PersonEnters` but not for `1392/11/14`, your query will not return that person at all, but the OP appears to want to return all persons.

Comment: @AndriyM Really you got that from that that comment.  All this for he want all records.  OP need to write a proper question.

Comment: The fact that all `Person` entries should be returned seemed to me clear enough from the beginning, the comment merely confirmed that for me. (I do agree that as a whole the question may not have been asked in the clearest of ways.)

Comment: @AndriyM OK I made change.  Not clearest?   The is one of the least clear comments I have ever had.

Comment: @AndriyM I (clearly?) meant [Management].[PersonEnters].[PersonID] is null

Comment: sorry everyone if my question was not clear,my english is not very good :((